# Problem running apollo server after nodejs upgrade (using nestjs and fastify)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, apollo-server, fastify

I've got a problem in my NestJs app. Project was running perfect until yesterday.

Apparently my node.js upgraded from `14.16.1` to `14.17.0`. So I changed this version number in my `engines` object, in `package.json`. I executed `yarn install` again, to make sure everything was there, and tried `yarn start:dev` (which translates to `nest start --watch`).

But my app isn't running =(
It seems like there's something wrong regarding my apollo-server-fastify:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.createHandler()`
    at ApolloServer.assertStarted (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-fastify/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:213:19)
    at ApolloServer.createHandler (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-fastify/dist/ApolloServer.js:22:14)
    at GraphQLModule.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql.module.js:150:45)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:16)
    at GraphQLModule.registerFastify (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql.module.js:143:24)
    at GraphQLModule.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql.module.js:118:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:323734) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:323734) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I know apollo and fastify aren't the best friends right now, I've faced an issue in the past where I needed to downgrade some package, I guess. Does anyone knows how to debug/fix this? I feel clueless.
Current package versions:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/graphql": "^7.7.0",
"@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^7.6.4",
"apollo-server-fastify": "^3.0.0-alpha.3",
"graphql": "^15.5.0",
```

(I've also tried to upgrade apollo-server-fastify to alpha 4, but the problem persists).

Comment: Checkout if the problem is [this one](https://twitter.com/matteocollina/status/1397506183427198983?s=20)

Comment: I guess it's not. Tried `yarn install`again, nothing changed. Then I found out fastify isn't a direct dependency for nestjs projects. Opened it's node_modules directory and it's current version is 3.14.0. So it was not updated recently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLDR

A temporary fix, until this issue is addressed by maintainers, is to copy [this patch file](https://github.com/troncali/nest-vue/blob/dev-nx/.yarn/patches/%40nestjs/graphql.patch) into your repository, then modify your package.json to use the following:

`"@nestjs/graphql": "patch:@nestjs/graphql@7.10.6#[YOUR/LOCAL/PATH]/graphql.patch"`

### Background

I ran into this same issue with my project. I'm not sure about the origin, but I did see that `apollo-server-fastify` was updated to 3.0.0-lambda.0 about 5 days ago and to 3.0.0-preview.0 a few hours ago.

I tracked the possible fix down to the `registerFastify` method in `@nestjs/graphql`.  The solution, I believe, is to call `await apolloServer.start()` on line 228 in `lib/graphql.module.ts` before the Apollo Server's `createHandler()` method is called.  I [opened an issue](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/1568) on the repository with more details, which you can follow until resolved.

I implemented the fix in the template repository I'm working on with `yarn patch @nestjs/graphql`. The repository is available on the `dev-nx` branch at [troncali/nest-vue](https://github.com/troncali/nest-vue/tree/dev-nx).  The patch is located in [`./.yarn/patches/@nestjs/graphql.patch`](https://github.com/troncali/nest-vue/blob/dev-nx/.yarn/patches/%40nestjs/graphql.patch).